# Weird Scala bug related to implicit conversions on default constructor parameters

Tags: scala

Consider the file *bug.scala*:

```
package sandbox

object Foo {
  implicit def stringToInt(s: String) = 5
}

import Foo._

class Boo(val a: Int = "foo" / 3) {
  val b: Int = "foo" / 3
  def c(d: Int = "foo" / 3) = d
}
```

It defines an implicit conversion, imports it, and uses it in three slightly different scenarios. Compile it:

```
E:\prog\scala\test>scalac bug.scala
bug.scala:9: error: value / is not a member of java.lang.String
class Boo(val a: Int = "foo" / 3) {
                       ^
one error found
```

The implicit conversion seems not to be working when used for a default constructor parameter, but works for the other scenarios.

Now watch this:

```
package sandbox

object Foo {
  implicit def stringToInt(s: String) = 5
}

object dummy

import Foo._
import dummy._

class Boo(val a: Int = "foo" / 3) {
  val b: Int = "foo" / 3
  def c(d: Int = "foo" / 3) = d
}
```

We've simply added an empty object and imported it. Now the file compiles without errors!

I see two possibilities here: 1) My head is messing with me. 2) There's a bug in the compiler. Can anyone confirm it's the latter?

(Using Scala 2.8.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a bug. I've lodged it on your behalf.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4141